# Do we need to use "are" three times in this sentence?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I said:

> Nanobots are bots that created from nanomaterials and comparable in size to a molecule.

But the teacher told me:

> Nanobots are bots that **are** created from nanomaterials and **are** comparable in size to a molecule.

What is the best choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Nanobots are bots that [?] created from nanomaterials and [?] comparable in size to a molecule.

Your sentence is not grammatical. Your teacher is right, you need to put in "are" two more times. But if you want to avoid that wordiness then you can rephrase the sentence.

One option is to omit "are bots".

> 1. Nanobots are created from nanomaterials and are comparable in size to a molecule.

Another option is to use a parenthetical and remove the coordinating conjunction.

> 2. Nanobots, created from nanomaterials, are comparable in size to a molecule.

---

**Edit:** As Michael Harvey correctly points in the comments, the second "are" is not mandatory for the sentence to be equally grammatical or idiomatic. Note that the first "are" preceding "created" is needed. Without the second "are", the sentence would be

> 3. Nanobots are created from nanomaterials and comparable in size to a molecule.

Both (1) and (3) are correct. Having said that, note how in both (1) and (2) I clearly wrote "option". This means that there may be several other ways to rephrase the sentence, and that those are just the one's [that] I am most comfortable with. For this particular sentence (OP's example), I feel including the second "are" improves the "flow" of the sentence. But that is my preference in this case. Others may say there is no such thing as "flow".

Comment: I would say that only the first missing 'are' (before 'created') is required; those following are optional, and would only be necessary if ambiguity would otherwise arise. Nuts are delicious, easy to eat, and cheap. This type of omission is called 'ellipsis'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your example is quite easy to follow and does not require the repeat use of "are'. But this sounds really off: *Nanobots are created from nanomaterials and comparable in size to a molecule.* Even though there is no ambiguity here, including the second "are" improves the flow of the sentence, at least to my ears.

Comment: My "ears" are relaxed about such things, and dictionaries and grammar texts support that. Merely saying that something "sounds bad", etc, doesn't work here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Okay, I respect that, its just a matter of preference or style then. The repeat use of "are" in my version is not incorrect. The absence of "are" in your version is not incorrect either. Like I said, to me, the inclusion of "are" improves the flow of the sentence. And why bring up "dictionaries and grammar texts"? I don't really see the point given I never said that they don't support your version or that your version is wrong. Note that I said OP's sentence is ungrammatical as it did not have the most important "are".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey And this - "doesn't work here" - sounds a bit condescending. Often, a grammatical sentence is phrased differently by different people depending on their style and intended audience (see I did not repeat "their" before "intended audience").

Comment: You may feel that "tennis balls are comparable is size to hen's eggs, spherical in shape, hollow, and often found in sports shops" does not "flow", but I feel that it "flows" better without all those repetitions of 'are'.

Comment: To be sure, it is a matter of preference or style.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Your tennis ball example flows better to me just the way it is. I never said that repeating auxiliary verbs or pronouns always improve readability or the "flow" of the sentence. I am just saying that in that particular sentence about nanobots, I like how it reads with the additional "are". All of my comments have addressed the repeat use of "are" in *OP's example*, and not once have I made a general statement saying that is what is to be done all the time.

Comment: (Native AmE here.) I concur with AIQ that the second "are", while not mandatory, helps the flow of the sentence (though context could change that). I think this is more than just personal preference or style. The sentence without the second "are" _can_ come across as sounding like a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis). The second "are" prevents that. But people can reasonably disagree about this.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is *almost* grammatical, but it simply needs to have the *that* removed:

> Nanobots are bots <s>that</s> created from nanomaterials and comparable in size to a molecule.

There is no reason to add *are* two more times, or make any other changes to your sentence, when all you have to do is remove the *that*.

Any other changes would not be to address the grammar, but to address style.